# Can views be created in PL/SQL Functions?

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm at the beginning of learning PL/SQL. My question is can views be created inside a function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION most_sold_item(in_year INT)
RETURN INT
IS

most_shipped_item INT := 0;

BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Shipped_Items AS
    SELECT ITEM_ID,SUM(QUANTITY) AS Total_Quantity 
    FROM ORDERS, ORDER_ITEMS
    WHERE Orders.Order_ID =Order_Items.Order_ID
    AND Status=1
    AND Order_Year=in_year
    GROUP BY Item_ID;

    SELECT Item_ID
    INTO most_shipped_item
    FROM Shipped_Items
    WHERE Total_quantity=(
    SELECT MAX(Total_Quantity)
    FROM Shipped_Items);
    

    return  most_shipped_item;
 
END;
/
```

Here's my code. There seems to be some kind of error which I just can't find. Can anyone please help me with this?
Thank you.

[Here's the snippet of the datatbase that I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zHj8.png)

Comment: No; use a `CTE`.

Comment: Also, you have a logic issue, even if that could be done.  If the `MAX` matches multiple `Item_ID`s, you'll produce more than one result and generate an error.  You don't really need a `VIEW` either.  This can be done in one statement without the `VIEW`, as long as you include logic to break any ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough idea of what you might do, if you wish to use a function for this (**Added logic to break ties**):

```
-- Estimated structure based on posted image:

CREATE TABLE orders (
   order_id     int primary key
 , client_id    int
 , order_year   int
 , status       int
);

CREATE TABLE order_items (
   order_id     int
 , item_id      int
 , quantity     int
 , ppu          int
 , primary key (order_id, item_id)
);

-- The adjusted function:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION most_sold_item(in_year INT)
RETURN INT
IS

most_shipped_item INT := 0;

BEGIN

   WITH shipped_items AS (
             SELECT ITEM_ID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS Total_Quantity 
               FROM ORDERS, ORDER_ITEMS
              WHERE Orders.Order_ID =Order_Items.Order_ID
                AND Status=1
                AND Order_Year=in_year
              GROUP BY Item_ID
        )
    SELECT Item_ID
      INTO most_shipped_item
      FROM Shipped_Items
     WHERE Total_quantity=(
         SELECT MAX(Total_Quantity)
           FROM Shipped_Items
        )
     ORDER BY item_id
     FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
    ;

    return  most_shipped_item;
 
END;
/
```

Don't forget to protect for the case where more than one `item_id` matches the `MAX`.  That's easy to do, but I don't know how you wish to handle that case.  I've adjusted the above solution to protect against this issue.

The question edit queue is full.  Here's an executable test case (without data) that could be added to the question:

[Executable test case, derived from the posted image (without data)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=563eb8cd21fb0558452af82fc29b5c50)

Comment: Thank you so much for reaching out. Could you please tell me how it could have been done without using view?

Comment: @lto The above solution doesn't use a `VIEW`.  As @Stu commented, this uses a `WITH clause`, called a `Common Table Expression (CTE)`.  It's part of standard SQL.  It's similar to a `VIEW`, but actually more powerful, and does not require creating a concrete object in the database.

Comment: Oh okay. You mentioned that this could've been done with one statement, would you kindly say how it that could've been done. It would be a great help to me.

Comment: @lto This is basically one statement.  You could have executed this outside the function by just parameterizing the `in_year` detail, for instance, with a prepared statement.  A function is ok, when used appropriately.  Without knowing more about how you're using the function, it's tough to provide too much more detail.  Feel free to ask a different question about your use of functions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your "original" question:

> Can views be created in PL/SQL Functions?

Yes, they can. Should you do it? Definitely **not**, that's not how Oracle works (in most cases). In Oracle, we create objects at SQL level and use them in SQL or PL/SQL, but we do not create them from PL/SQL.

Anyway, here you are; read comments within code. I used Scott's sample schema as I don't have your tables, but the principle remains the same.

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test(par_deptno in number)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    -- you can't perform DDL in PL/SQL procedures unless they are
  5    -- autonomous transactions
  6    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  7    retval number;
  8  begin
  9    -- you can't perform DML in a function unless you use dynamic SQL
 10    execute immediate
 11      'create or replace view v_emp as ' ||
 12      '  select ename, sal ' ||
 13      '  from emp ' ||
 14      '  where deptno = ' || dbms_assert.enquote_literal(par_deptno);
 15
 16    -- you can't use an ordinary SELECT statement because at time of
 17    -- procedure compilation view V_EMP doesn't exist yet, so compile
 18    -- would fail
 19    execute immediate
 20      'select sum(sal) from v_emp ' into retval;
 21
 22    return retval;
 23  end;
 24  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test (20) from dual;

F_TEST(20)
----------
     10875
```

What does the view contain?

```
SQL> select * from v_emp;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SMITH             800
JONES            2975
SCOTT            3000
ADAMS            1100
FORD             3000

SQL>
```